# try/catch within decimal method c#

Tags: c#, methods, try-catch

First up, this is an assignment I'm working on, but this is not a requirement of it, just something I wish to use. I'm trying to use the try/catch statement with my decimal method.

```
    private decimal NewCar()
    {
        decimal newCar = 0.00m;

        try
        {
            newCar = decimal.Parse(vehicleTextBox.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry (Format Exception). \n" + "Please enter a valid decimal number.");
            Keyboard.Focus(vehicleTextBox);
            vehicleTextBox.SelectAll();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry (General Exception). \n" + "Please enter a valid decimal number.");
            Keyboard.Focus(vehicleTextBox);
            vehicleTextBox.SelectAll();
            return;
        }

        if (newCar < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry (Negative Value). \n" + "Please enter a valid decimal number.");
            Keyboard.Focus(vehicleTextBox);
            vehicleTextBox.SelectAll();
            return;
        }

        return newCar;
    }
```

I get an error saying that "An object of a type convertible to 'decimal' is required", but if I put the newCar variable there, or delete the return statements in the try/catch, I get too many message boxes and it doesn't stop the calculations. I need this to be a decimal method to use in other calculations.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do not use try catch to find out if it is a valid input or not. In general this is not good practice. Use Decimal.TryParse instead..

Comment: On which event you've called newcar method ? Can you plz show that code too . And you can't return from a method having some return type using return statement which returns nothing .

Comment: I couldn't get this to work the way I wanted and decided to use the `try-catch` within my `calculate_button` method, and just referenced `decimal.Parse(vehicleTextBox.Text)` in the different methods used for calculations.                                                                                      Everything seems fine now, thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said your method will return a decimal. So you *must* return a decimal. You cannot just write `return`, as that indicates you are returning nothing.

Now, it's likely you should move your error handling out of the method, and simply allow the exceptions to bubble up. Since your method is parsing the car value (and by the way, your method name should indicate that, `NewCar` indicates that it's creating a new car object), it shouldn't necessarily interact with the user. It's only purpose should be parsing the text and giving you a decimal.

So you have two options:

1. Your method returns an error code (for example, -1), so that you can return a suitable value. Another option is to create a wrapper class which stores a 'Successful' flag, the data, and possible exceptions.
2. Let the exception simply bubble up.

Comment: I did have the error handling outside the method to begin with, so this makes sense to me, I was just trying to see if there was a way to make it work, so I'll try the `TryParse` method mentioned below by @Saeed Jahed

Answer (score 1):

To add to Rob's correct and excellent answer, I'd also suggest using `TryParse(...)` over catching exceptions.

```
private void NewCar() {
    decimal newCarValue;

    if (decimal.TryParse(vehicleTextBox.Text, out newCarValue))
    {
        // valid decimal.
        // now validate the value of decmial
        if (newCarValue >= 0)
        {
            // All good.  Do the work with car here.
        }
        else
        {
            // complain
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // complain
    }
}
```

In your case, you are catching the `Exception` class which is a bad idea.  Suppose your code had a bug, and it resulted in a `NullReferenceException` while creating the car. You'll be telling the user that they've entered an invalid value, where in reality it's just a bug in the code that is being buried.

Comment: The TryParse method requires an `out` keyword on the `newCarValue` variable since it is an out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the compiler complains because all your return statements except for the last one are incorrect, you're not returning decimal. I recommend you to take the logic for the MessageBoxes outside of this method.
If you want to check the number was converted correctly I would recommend you to use the TryParse method intead:

```
private void TheFunctionThatWasUsingNewCar() {

    decimal newCar;
    //send the uninitialized newCar variable to TryParse. If everything went ok, the variable will contain the equivalente decimal value.
    if(! Decimal.TryParse(vehicleTextBox.Text, out newCar)){
        //You can be almost certain that if the conversion failed it's because of the format
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry (Format Exception). \n" + "Please enter a valid decimal number.");
        KeyBoard.Focus(vehicleTextBox);
        vehicleTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
    //Validate the converted number was not negative
    if(newCar < 0){
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry (Negative Value). \n" + "Please enter a valid decimal number.");
        KeyBoard.Focus(vehicleTextBox);
        vehicleTextBox.SelectAll();
    }

    //At this point you have your newCar variable and it's valid.
}
```